# from a service use: runOnUiThread or AsyncTask or Handler or Post

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm writing a voip application. It is based on a service that manages the voip logic and a UI to make calls, answer, etc.
What is the best way to update the UI from the service:

- runOnUiThread or
- AsyncTask or
- Handler or
- Post

When to use one method over the other?
I know that runOnUiThread is problematic since it might cause events to be ran out of order (in case the thread is already the UI thread).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, you can't update the screen directly from service. You have to use broadcast receiver to catch your broadcast from service. I guess AsyncTask  itself uses runOnUiThread, but it provides nice way to execute one method in background thread and put results in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call bindService() to bind to the Service. Then you can use AsyncTask or a Handler to get Informations out of the Service.

For more read: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html)